# How to resolve the error about 'A partially-completed form was found'?

Tags: 7, webforms, debugging

Yesterday I have updated [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module from 7.x-4.0-beta3 to 7.x-4.13.

After doing so, I am getting this notification message, throughout the site:

> A partially-completed form was found. Please complete the remaining portions

I have also checked some threads.

When I check log entries I got this error :

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$is_draft in webform_client_form()

And deleting partially filled nid in webform submissions table is not working for me.

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "*deleting partially filled nid in webform submissions table*" (as in your question) seems to not solve your issue, you may want to have a look at [comment nr 2 in issue 2560907](https://www.drupal.org/node/2560907#comment-10335789), which states:

> A webform node is being displayed on that page and there is a draft submission for the current user. You don't have to find the id -- the form will be displayed, unless theming or another module is preventing it.